# Select which application to (NOT) update

Tags: applications, google-play-store, application-autoupdate

I always knew how to disable the auto update for a specific app.
But since some time Google decided to forbid this useful functionality and force the users to update their app.
And I mainly do NOT use the Google Apps and don't want to update them (but I want to  update all my others non-Google apps).

How can I do it?

Before I could:

1. Go to *Google Play*
2. Select *My apps*
3. Select the desired app
4. Click the phone *Menu* button
5. Deselect the *Auto-update* tick box

Now is no more possible.
How could I achieve the same result?

Comment: Am I missing something? If you go to Google Play's product page of the specific app, and bring up the Settings, the setting allows you to toggle Auto-Update by individual app. Is this a different version of Google Play? mine is v5.0.31

Comment: I guess my smartphone has some problem. I tried for half an hour and no menu was appearing. Tried now and the voice _"auto-update"_ appears, but it disappear if I click on it..    
And it doesn't deselect. Mmmmh..